# Were Omens Known Before Hawkwings Sons Set Sail?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

In the *Wheel of Time* series, the Seanchan are great believers in omens. Our Andoran friends believe it is all superstitious nonsense, quite similar to how the Seanchan view tales of trollocs and other shadowspawn.

Were the omens know before Artur Hawkwing's sons set sail across the Aryth Ocean, then simply forgotten? Or was it something they discovered while they lived on their separate continent? I've scanned through the books and supplemental material I have on hand, but I haven't found anything obvious to indicate either way.

Comment: Couldn't you just ask your wife? :)

Comment: Yeah well...we're not exactly on speaking terms.

Comment: Their whole culture is completely different from any country on the other side of the sea, this is just one of many things. The boring but realistic explanation is that any country living in isolation ought to become more and more different over time.

Comment: I usually back-interpret the Seanchan's penchant for omens as a result of their exposure to Min's ability as a "Truthsayer" (or whatever they call it), and the Seanchan just codified all the auras that appear around people and then see them everywhere they look. So it's a result of that ability being less common on Rand's side of the Aryth Ocean.

Comment: I like that interpretation a lot.